# O que "[ ]" significa na declaração do método

Tags: c#

Eu tenho o seguinte método

```
public BITalinoFrame[] Read(int nbSamples)
{
    try
    {
        return device.ReadFrames(nbSamples);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        WriteLog("Error reading the frames: " + ex.Message);
    }    
    return null;
}
```

o que eu preciso saber é o que significa a parte:

```
public BITalinoFrame[] Read(int nbSamples)
```

Comment: Que este método retorna um array do tipo `BITalinoFrame`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Significa que o tipo a ser retornado é um `array` de elementos da classe  `BITalinoFrame`.

por exemplo, o método abaixo retorna um `array` de inteiros:

```
public int[] ListaInteiros()
{
    int[] lista = new int[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    return lista;
}
```